# Email error on #android-dev irc channel

Tags: irc

I try to register my email and password and it tells me this, `<devon.west@outlook.com> is not a valid email address.` That is the only email I have. Why am I getting the error message?

Comment: because the server thinks your mail isn't valid? What did you enteR?

Comment: /msg NickServ REGISTER <my password> <devon.west@outlook.com>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually including the `<` and `>` symbols around your email (and password) then that's your problem, as those shouldn't be included.

Comment: Thank you @techie007! I just want to let everyone know that it has been resolved with the help of the people on the #freenode irc chat channel. It took me several hours, but I finally figured it out and was finally able to chat on the #android-dev channel. :^)